# Best approach to driving custom RGB mechanical keyboard LEDs

Tags: embedded, led-matrix, keyboard, ws2812b, rp2040

I am in the middle of designing a custom mechanical keyboard and have just finished the PCB schematic, but before I spend a few hours placing and routing components, I thought I might ask y'all a few questions that have been bugging me. (I am doing a 65% keyboard with 67 keys laid out in a 5x15 matrix and using 75x WS2812B LED chipset for reference)

I am designing the PCB around the RP2040 and I am somewhat familiar with the PIO functionality, but would really prefer to not have to go through all of the logic for driving an LED matrix. I am wondering if it might be worth it to use two microcontrollers, one for handling the keyboard scanning FSM and one for driving LEDs as it seems that there is not a whole lot of support for driving LED matrices with an RP2040 microcontroller. There is a decent amount of support for using the RP2040 with HUB75 LED matrices, but I believe using WS2812B would be better as it has its own controller and I can dedicate the LEDs to be on 100% of the time rather than scanning across the matrix as is the protocol for HUB75.

I know there are different NeoPixel libraries out there and maybe I just need to play around with it, but it seems like they have a pretty bare-bones structure. Maybe I do just need to sit down and hand-develop this project for a few months...

Any thoughts, hints or helpful comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The rp2040 is already dual-core. What additional ease works a separate third core give?

Comment: I mean, the whole very low level, highly clocked design principle of the RP2040 is essentially made for controlling ws2812-alike buses. Also, what do you foresee being problematic about driving the LED matrix all the time? You have a full core you can dedicate to that, running at 133 MHz! You don't even have to think about performance to make this work.

Comment: While technically I agree with Marcus, OTH: If it is a one-off, and one extra microcontroller makes your work easier, why not? I bet the cost of an extra chip is a lot lower than your hours.

Comment: When I said use a different controller, what I should have more clearly stated is that using an SPI bus to communicate the key being pressed to a microcontroller that has more support for driving WS2812B matrices

Comment: You are using WS2812Bs. Those are not matrices. They are daisy-chained and use a custom serial protocol.

Comment: @user253751 just because they are WIRED in series doesn’t mean you cannot array them as a matrix. I’ve made a few addressable LED matrices before, just not with the RP2040 microprocessor.

Comment: @mistasef Okay but then you don't treat them as a matrix in software, still just one chain